# Bind a directory to a docker container

Tags: docker, containers, bind, directory

I'm building a test project that requires a module outside of the project directory. The project folder is in docker, and I would like to bind that module directory to the docker container of my project. Is it even possible to do it? Or am I asking the wrong question? By the way, I'm still new to docker so I'm just trying things out.

Answer (score 32):

My understand is, you need mount the host folder to the container. So try this:

```
docker run -v /host/project_folder:/container/project -t avian/project_image bash
```

#### explanation

- `-v` -  --volume=[]            Bind mount a volume
- `/host/project_folder` - host server's folder
- `/container/project` - container's folder

### Update:

The latest docker version (v1.9.1) support a new command `volume`. So you should be easier to manage volume in docker.

```
# For example, I need attach a volume to mysql container.
docker volume create --name mysql-data
docker run --name mysql -v mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql
```

With that, you can delete container `mysql` any time, without lost your database data.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `-v` option to mount a `volume` (e.g. your folder) into the container. More details can be found [in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).

E.g., from `ghost` blog platform's Dockerfile example:

```
docker run -v /data/ghost:/var/lib/ghost -d ghost
```

Which maps `/data/ghost` on the local drive to `/var/lib/ghost` inside the container.

You can also specify another docker container as the `source` of the data using `--volumes-from` option.