# Add project sources to docker container at run time

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am quite new to docker. I worked a `Dockefile` that copies my project sources and them builds the application. The building process is quite complex and should be done in the container's environment; not the host machine. 
So the Dockerfile look something like this:

```
FROM base-image

RUN mkdir -p /proj/branches/www
COPY ./proj/branches/mybranch/* /proj/branches/mybranch/
RUN chown root:www-data -R /proj

COPY config-and-build.sh .
RUN /config-and-build.sh

EXPOSE 80
CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

The project source folder is big (~3 G). And so, building the image takes a while; copying the files and compiling some sources. Most of the time I will not change the sources of the compiled programs so this is a waste of time.

I am trying to understand how volumes work to mount the sources. But my understanding is that the volume is defined at runtime, so the `config-and-build` script cannot be done.

Is there a way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your script `config-and-build.sh` to ENTRYPOINT & integrate your CMD `apachectl -D FOREGROUND` in that entrypoint script itself.

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Once that's done you can use host bind volumes `-v` with `docker run` to mount your project directory directly inside the container which will remove the dependency of copying project using the Dockerfile.

Ref - [Bind a directory to a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183978/bind-a-directory-to-a-docker-container)

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to make the source code available is to use [volume bind-mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). This will allow you to give the container access to a directory that is on the host machine.

You can achieve that via  mounting the directory containing the source code using the `-v` argument when starting the container.

```
docker run -v <source-code-dir-on-machine>:<container-source-code-dir> <image-name> ...
```

The host directory and the container directory will be in sync, which will enable you to avoid rebuilding the image wherever there are new code changes.